# Incremental Database Copy from Azure SQL DB to Snowflake

Tags: sql-server, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I would like to upload a table from Azure SQL DB to Snowflake using Azure Factory.

Right now I am using the pipeline "copy data" with source and destination. The entire Events table (about 2GB) from BlaBla database is copied. (without creation CSV file)

[image]
[image]
[image]

But, I can't find a solution how to use incremental loading, so that not the whole database is copied, but only newly added rows. For example, create a trigger every 5 minutes, and every 5 minutes the rows that appeared in the table Events were copied to the tables in Snowflake without any duplicates.

And are there any options to use access the api to send directly the data to Snowflake? If so, could you please share an example?

Please help me with advice, as the ideas are already on the way out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform incremental loading from Azure SQL Database to Snowflake using Azure Data Factory, you can follow the below steps:

1. Select a column in the source SQL table that can be used to identify new or updated records for every run. Normally, the data in this selected column (for example, `last_modified_time` or `ID`) keeps increasing when rows are created or updated. The maximum value in this column can be used as a watermark.
2. Prepare a SQL table to store the watermark value.
3. Create a pipeline with the following activities:

   a. Lookup activities: Use a query to retrieve the maximum value of the watermark column from the destination table in Snowflake in the first lookup activity. (This value is stored in watermark table).  In the second lookup activity, take the maximum value of watermark column from the source SQL table.

   b. Copy activity: Use a SQL query to retrieve the new or updated records from the source table in Azure SQL Database. Use the watermark column to filter the records based on the maximum value retrieved in the previous step. Copy the filtered records to the destination table in Snowflake.

   c. Stored procedure activity: Use a stored procedure to update the new watermark value in the SQL database watermark table.
4. Schedule the pipeline to run at a specific interval, for example, every 5 minutes using triggers.

For more details, refer the [microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview#loading-new-and-changed-files-only-by-using-lastmodifieddate) on incremental loading from SQL database.